# How to make my <li> move down even if using the “top” attribute

Tags: html, css

```
<style type="text/css">
  #poption {
    font-family: Segoe UI Emoji, arial;
    color: white;
    padding: 1px;
    top: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <li width="1">
    <a id="poption">Profile Options</a>
  </li>
</body>
```

I’m trying to make it go more down but it doesn’t move. Can someone tell me how to make it so I can make it move more down?

Comment: try `margin-top` instead `top` and add `display:inline-block`.

Comment: What is `width="1"` supposed to be? Tell us, in which tutorial did you find this attribute?

Comment: `top` only makes sense with a non-static `position`.

Comment: Your HTML is broken... you can't have an `<li>` without being inside of an `<ul>` or `<ol>`.

Comment: You also cannot have a `<style></style>` container as a sibling of the `<body></body>` container.

Comment: There is a lot wrong with your code. Try taking some lessons on codecademy.com or something.

Comment: People are correct the code is not written well. I would usually use an external stylesheet rather than having it in the same file as the code.

That said you can use margin-top but use this on the "li" instead of the "a" only thing is if you were to add more "li" elements to the page then each one would have a margin-top.

see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8v3fwquf/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to position the element so it will move relative to where it's at. Currently, it's set to the default `position:static`. Add `position:relative;` to `#poption`. Then you can change the `top` value.